# Laravel Eloquent Query Builder

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

How can I query that given sql in Laravel 5.1 eloquent builder?

```
"SELECT referer, count(referer) AS listRefererCount FROM sss_options  WHERE shorturl=:shorturl GROUP BY referer"
```

Comment: Have you tried anything or searched at all? It is actually quite simple to query.

Comment: You should try yourself first and if you fail then ask for help. but at least show some efforts this is an easy query to build. read laravel docs for example.

Comment: If I can I wouldn't ask it on Stackoverflow. Please give me my answer if you really can help. 

Thanks

Comment: @OhidulIslam you should at least try looking in the docs. There are examples of how to query using `where()`, `groupBy()`, `count()`. These are all chainable and so it is just a matter of putting them together.

Answer (score 2):

Here is it for you then.

```
YourModel::select('referer',DB::raw('count(referer) AS listRefererCount')
->where('shorturl','=',$variable)
->groupBy('referer')
->get();
```

Comment: Thanks you, This is it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// "SELECT referer, count(referer) AS listRefererCount FROM sss_options  WHERE shorturl=:shorturl GROUP BY referer"
// this is the model class
class SssOptions extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    protected $table = 'sss_options';

}


// below is the query builder
$q = SssOptions::query();
$shorturl = 'your cond';
$q->getQuery()
    ->select(['referer', new \Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression('count(referer) AS listRefererCount')])
    ->where('shorturl', $shorturl)
    ->groupBy('referer')
;

var_dump($q->toSql()); // the sql
var_dump($q->get()); // the result
```